# Can I lookup an EJB from another EJB?

Tags: java, ejb

I have an EJB and it has a method that makes a lookup to another EJB.
I'm having a NameNotFoundException with this code.

ServiceEJBImpl :

```
@Stateless(name = "ServiceEJB", mappedName = "AppAcaAvaliacaoAtuarial-ModelAvaliacaoAtuarial-ServiceEJB")
public class ServiceEJBImpl implements ServiceEJB, ServiceEJBLocal{   

public void persistConflicts(List<Conflict> conflicts)  
{
    ConflictDAOLocal conflictDAO =  (ConflictDAOLocal) BeanLocator.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/local/ConflictDAO");
    conflictDAO.persistAll(conflicts);
}
```

ConflictDAOLocal:

```
@Local
public interface ConflitoDAOLocal{
   void persistAll(List<Conflict> conflicts);
}
```

That's my lookupMethod:

```
public static Object lookup(String jndiName) {
    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext();
        return context.lookup(jndiName);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("...",ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            context.close();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("...",ex);
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/local/ConflictDAO</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
<local>br.gov.rj.rioprev.sigap.acompatuarial.avalatuarial.model.dao.ConflictDAOLocal</local>
    <ejb-link>ConflictDAO</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>

 <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/local/ServiceEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>br.gov.rj.rioprev.sigap.acompatuarial.avalatuarial.model.dao.ServiceEJBLocal</local>
    <ejb-link>ServiceEJB</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Is there a problem instantiating a new context when making a lookup to an EJB inside another EJB that already has a context instantiated?

I'm not considering @EJB annotation.

Comment: Sure can do, but since you don't tell us what the name is, not much chance to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit being more specific

Comment: Are all your EJBs in a WAR file?

Comment: They are all in a JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you lookup with the correct jndi name you should be able to do it, im not an expert but if you are running this in a web server it would tell you the jndi at momment of the deploy, also you dont really need to create your own lookup, there is one already done that you can use it (actually you are using it but thats just a matter of style), the best aproach maybe is to give your initial context the web server's context, it depends I belive in every web server it should be done something like this

```
try{             

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); //This is the one that you have to change depending on your webserver
        Context context = new InitialContext(prop);         
         ejbean = (BitacoraBeanRemote)context.lookup("ejb:/EjbSite//BitacoraBean!some.package.bean.BitacoraBeanRemote"); // This is the lookup, it could be a local or a remote interface depending on needs            
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I was writing when you edit your post just make sure your jndi name is fine "java:comp/env/ejb/local/ConflictDAO", you should probably change it you app is not finding this particular jndi

Comment: When I lookup ConflictDAO from a regular class it works fine. My problem is when I want to lookup from an EJB like ServiceEJB.
When I use @EJB works fine to...

Comment: Always use `Context context = new InitialContext();` without properties when performing in-server JNDI lookups.

Comment: The way to lookup its different depending on where its called or where its located, try changing "java:" by "ejb:" everything is running in the same server right? try what Steve said (get an initialContext) and then lookup like this: ejb:comp/env/ejb/local/ConflictDAO

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a JNDI lookup in an EJB for a dependent EJB, you need to specify your `ejb-local-ref` elements in an `ejb-jar.xml` file in you EJB jar:

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd"
         version="3.2">

    <enterprise-beans>
        ...
        <session>
            <ejb-name>ServiceEJB</ejb-name>

            <ejb-local-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>ejb/local/ConflictDAO</ejb-ref-name>
                <local>br.gov.rj.rioprev.sigap.acompatuarial.avalatuarial.model.dao.ConflictDAOLocal</local>
                <ejb-link>ConflitoDAO</ejb-link>
            </ejb-local-ref>
        </session>
        ...
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

You must provide an `ejb-local-ref` element for each EJB that looks up another EJB.

Each EJB in an EJB jar has it's own `java:comp/env` namespace, whereas a webapp WAR file has a single `java:comp/env` namespace.